# Reducing Congruences modulo an ideal of a ring of algebraic integers to congruences over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a number field of degree $d$, let $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$ be the ring of $\mathbb{F}$-integers, and let $\mathfrak{I}$ be an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$ for which the quotient ring $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}/\mathfrak{I}$ is finite—say, containing $\varrho$ distinct equivalence classes, which I'll label as $\mathfrak{I}_{0},\ldots,\mathfrak{I}_{\varrho-1}$, where $\mathfrak{I}_{0}$ is the equivalence class of $\mathfrak{I}$ itself. Next, let $\gamma_{1},\ldots,\gamma_{d}\in\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$ be a basis of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, and write elements of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$ as $d$-tuples $\left(n_{1},\ldots,n_{d}\right)\in\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ with respect to this basis.

Now, suppose: $$x=\sum_{\ell=1}^{d}n_{\ell}\gamma_{\ell}\in\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$$ satisfies $x\overset{\mathfrak{I}}{\equiv}\mathfrak{I}_{j}$ for some $j\in\left\{ 0,\ldots,\varrho-1\right\}$  (i.e., there is an element $x_{j}\in\mathfrak{I}_{j}$ so that $x-x_{j}\in\mathfrak{I}$). My question is: is there a general procedure for converting the congruence $x\overset{\mathfrak{I}}{\equiv}\mathfrak{I}_{j}$ to a congruence (or system thereof) involving the $n_{\ell}$s? Also, is there a choice of basis $\gamma_{1},\ldots,\gamma_{d}$ which minimizes the amount of work needed to do this conversion?

For example, let $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$, $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}=\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{2}\right]$, and let $\mathfrak{I}=\left\langle \sqrt{2}\right\rangle$. Choose $\gamma_{1}=1$ and $\gamma_{2}=\sqrt{2}$, and let $x=a+b\sqrt{2}$ be arbitrary. Since $\left\langle 2\right\rangle$  is a subring of $\left\langle \sqrt{2}\right\rangle$, it follows that everything congruent to $0$ mod $2$ will also be congruent to $0$ mod $\sqrt{2}$. Now, since $2\in\mathfrak{I}$, it follows that $a+b\sqrt{2}\overset{\sqrt{2}}{\equiv}a$. If $a$ is even, then $a\overset{\sqrt{2}}{\equiv}0$. If $a$ is odd, then $a\overset{2}{\equiv}1$. Since $\left\langle \sqrt{2}\right\rangle$  contains the subring $\left\langle 2\right\rangle$, the congruence $a\overset{2}{\equiv}1$ then “lifts” to the congruence $a\overset{\sqrt{2}}{\equiv}1$.

Consequently, $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is congruent to $0$ mod $\sqrt{2}$ if and only if $a$ is congruent to $0$ mod $2$, and $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is congruent to $1$ mod $\sqrt{2}$ if and only if $a$ is congruent to $1$ mod $2$. Since this exhausts all possible equivalence classes of $a$ mod $2$, this then completely classifies the ways in which $a+b\sqrt{2}$ can fall into different equivalence classes mod $\sqrt{2}$.

I can do this simple case, but anything of dimension three or higher just boggles my mind. Algebra is *not* my strong suit by any stretch of the imagination, so any help in dealing with the general problem would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea that reduces the problem to solving a system of linear Diophantine equations. I would not be surprised if there are better methods, I'd be interested to see.

The ring $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F}$ is Noetherian, so every ideal is finitely-generated. Let $\mathfrak{I} \subset \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F}$ be such an ideal, and let the generators be $\alpha_1
, \ldots, \alpha_n$ (actually, since $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F}$ is also a Dedekind domain, every ideal can be generated by at most $2$ elements, but we don't need this fact here).

An element $x \in \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F}$ is contained in $\mathfrak{I}$ iff there exist $\beta_i \in \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F}$ such that $x = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \beta_i\alpha_i$. Write each $\beta_i$ as a linear combination of the integral basis of $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F}$: $$\beta_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^d b_{ij} \gamma_j\text{ , where }b_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Also write each $\alpha_i\gamma_j$ as a linear combination of the $\gamma_k$: $$\alpha_i\gamma_j = \sum\limits_{k=1}^da_{ijk}\gamma_k\text{ , where }a_{ijk} \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Hence we have $$x = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^db_{ij}\alpha_i\gamma_j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^d\sum\limits_{k=1}^db_{ij}a_{ijk}\gamma_k = \sum\limits_{k=1}^d\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^da_{ijk}b_{ij}\right)\gamma_k$$

Note that the coefficients $a_{ijk} \in \mathbb{Z}$ are known in principle, given the generators $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ of $\mathfrak{I}$, and the integral basis $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_d$ of $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F}$.

So if we are given $x = \sum\limits_{k=1}^dc_k\gamma_k$, we can determine whether $x \in \mathfrak{I}$ by checking if the system of linear equations $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^da_{ijk}b_{ij} = c_k\text{ , where }k = 1, \ldots, d$$ has solutions $b_{ij}$ over the integers. This ends up being a system of $d$ linear Diophantine equations in $nd$ unknowns, which can be solved with the Smith normal form.

---

We can apply this to your example, where $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. Let's look at the ideal $\mathfrak{I} = \langle \sqrt{2} \rangle$. An integral basis for $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{F}$ is given by $\{1, \sqrt{2}\}$. Then we have $\alpha_1 = \sqrt{2}$, $\gamma_1 = 1$ and $\gamma_2 = \sqrt{2}$. We find $\alpha_1\gamma_1 = \sqrt{2}$ and $\alpha_1\gamma_2 = 2$. Hence $a_{111} = 0$, $a_{112} = 1$, $a_{121} = 2$ and $a_{122} = 0$.

Given $x = c_1 + c_2\sqrt{2}$, membership in $\mathfrak{I}$ is determined by solving the system:
$$2b_{12} = c_1$$
$$b_{11} = c_2$$

This has integer solutions for $b_{ij}$ iff $c_1$ is even. Therefore $c_1 + c_2\sqrt{2} \in \langle\sqrt{2}\rangle$ iff $c_1$ is even, which is what you already concluded too.

---

So far I only talked about how to determine membership in the ideal $\mathfrak{I}$, but not membership in its cosets. But using the procedure as above, we end up with a system of linear Diophantine equations. If this system has no solutions, then we know that $x$ lies in another coset of $\mathfrak{I}$. But I think we can read it off from the Smith normal form and the congruence class of the $c_k$ modulo the diagonal entries of this matrix. I'll come back to add details on this later if I can think of it.

Comment: Because I'm really dense when it comes to figuring out details, would you mind showing how to do the case for the co-sets of $\mathfrak{I}$? I'd really appreciate it. That being said, is it possible that, given $\mathfrak{I}$ and the $\alpha_{i}$s that generate it, can you extend the set of $\alpha_{i}$s into a basis for $ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$ over $ \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Also, given $\mathfrak{I}$, and a congruence $x\overset{\mathfrak{I}}{\equiv}\mathfrak{I}_{j}$, how do I rewrite this congruence so that $\mathfrak{I}$ and $\mathfrak{I}_{j}$ get replaced by actual elements of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}} $ Example: for $\mathfrak{I}=\left\langle \sqrt{2}\right\rangle$, congruence mod $\mathfrak{I}$ becomes congruence mod $\sqrt{2}$, and the different equivalence classes mod $\sqrt{2}$ are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that $\mathfrak{I}=\left\langle \alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}\right\rangle$  and $x\overset{\mathfrak{I}}{\equiv}\mathfrak{I}_{j}$ and $x\overset{\mathfrak{I}}{\equiv}\mathfrak{I}_{j}$ then implies that  $x\overset{\alpha_{i}}{\equiv}a_{i,j}$ for each $i\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,n\right\}$  for some $a_{i,j}\in\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$?